# How to change color what is under self.view

Tags: ios

I want to change color what is unde `self.view`. For example in navigation controller I just can change background of navigation controller, but how to change it on simple view controller ?

[image]

Comment: What is the thing that you have outlined in red?

Comment: It is view under `self.view` and I want to change color of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the `window` that the app runs in.

You shouldn't really be messing with it. Your `UIViewController`'s views should be covering it completely.

Comment: Ah, yes it `window` view, thanks. How I can access it from `View Controller.m` file. From `AppDelegate.m` it is just `[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`, but how to do it from VC?

Comment: You can get the window using... `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];`

Comment: I use this `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`, but it don't change background color.

Comment: Like I said. You shouldn't be messing around with it. I doubt you can actually change the background colour of it. Your VCs should be covering it completely. The user shouldn't even see it.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in iOS7, you can make container view controllers to present other view controllers. Changing the background color of the container view would effectively provide the functionality you're looking for